# Cant use insert with subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, insert-into, ansi-sql-92

This problem is really weird and I believe related with Access itself.

I`m trying to insert this way (really simplified version, but anyway the error is the same):

```
INSERT INTO phones(a, b)
select * from ( select C, D from banks) AS BB;
```

Access returns error, saying that:

> Instruction INSERT INTO consist unknown field C

Then I tried another query, that looks the same:

```
INSERT INTO phones(a, b)
select BB.* from ( select C, D from banks) AS BB;
```

> Error: The number of field isn't matching.

However query without subquery works awesome!

```
INSERT INTO phones(a, b)
select C, D from banks;
```

So that is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can  see now, Access cant match fields itself , this why names in the subquery should be the same:

```
INSERT INTO phones(a, b)
select * from ( select C as a , D as b from banks) AS BB;
```

Wasted more than 1 hour to solve.

Comment: Why subquery `INSERT INTO phones(a, b) select C, D from banks;` didn't work?

Comment: @lad2025 As I said  that code works, because it doesnt have any subquery